# Unable to complete a simple job with Pyspark on Jupyter Notebook (OS: Windows 10 , Running code locally - single node)

Tags: windows, pyspark, jupyter

Data source: - https://www.kaggle.com/saurav9786/amazon-product-reviews
Total rows: ~ 7M (311 MBs)

I am trying to use Pyspark on Jupyter Notebook. I am able to successfully setup a Sparksession, test it and read the above reviews data (locally stored) directly as a spark dataframe. However, I am not able to successfully complete even the simplest of data manipulation jobs, such as simply count the distinct userids , or not able to even show the top 10 rows. The job runs endlessly.

I have setup and configured my sparksession using the below code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('local[*]')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

I read the dataset as a spark dataframe using the below code:

```
d_schema = StructType().add("userid","string").add("productid","string").add("rating","integer").add("datetime","string")
spark_ratings = spark.read.csv("source_data.csv",schema=d_schema,header=None)
```

Reads the data in 672 ms.

But After this I tried the following:

```
spark_ratings.select(F.countDistinct("userid")).show()
```

OR

```
spark_ratings.show(10)
```

And the job keeps running forever, does not throw an error but doesn't deliver the results.

I am a beginner at using Pyspark, am I missing something critical here?

I have a 12 GB RAM and Intel i5 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long did you waited for the result?
Actually, spark is lazily evaluated and doesn't process your data until an action is applied to it. So reading the data in 672 ms is just it is added in the DAG but as soon you apply action show() then it actually reads the complete data in memory and gives you the output.

So, it may take some time depending upon your data size.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shubham, I waited for more than 10 minutes. After which, I killed the job thinking thinking something might be wrong. My data size is 311 MBs

Comment: Don't just kill the job...keep it running...spark jobs are slow at first but gives performance boost when there are multiple transformations need to be done...let it fail itself and wait... I'd suggest

Comment: Thanks Shubham, that actually worked. It took a long time for the first few queries and then started working smoothly afterwards

Comment: I did but it says my vote would be recorded but not publicly displayed because I have <15 reputation